# Studies on reincarnation of Ian Stevenson

Tags: reincarnation

Some people claim that reincarnation is "scientific",  since there were [scientific studies of reincarnation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reincarnation_research). They refer especially to [Ian Stevenson's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Stevenson) reseach.

Is this still considered "scientific"? Can anyone give a brief review of works of this guy?

Answer (score 3):

The Skeptic's Dictionary includes [a 'skeptical' article about Ian Stevenson's work](http://www.skepdic.com/stevenson.html), which says,

> "There is nothing that could be discovered by this method that could ever falsify the reincarnation hypothesis."

Stevenson spent a lifetime (well, from 1961, starting at about age 43) looking for stories which he couldn't prove to be false, and found some.

It says that he provided "evidence, but not compelling evidence".